# convert a text to hash in node js

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, hashcode

I want to convert a text to hash id of numbers using node js. Already have a java program to convert but same kind of implementation to be done using node js.

## Java Code

```
    public static long generateId(String text) {

    byte[] buffer = null;
    MessageDigest md = null;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        md.reset();
        buffer = text.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8);

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    md.update(buffer);
    byte[] digest = md.digest();
    String hexStr = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
        hexStr += Integer.toString((digest[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1);
    }
    long hashid = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < hexStr.length(); i++)
        hashid += Math.abs((long) Math.pow(27, 10 - i) * ('a' - (1 + hexStr.charAt(i))));

    return hashid;
}
```

I was able to convert into nodejs upto digest after this I am unable to proceed.

```js
function generateHashCode()
{
var text = '9/01/2017'+'xx'+'405'+''+'SDD'+'MDD'+'9';
var crypto = require('crypto');
console.log(crypto.createHash('SHA1').update(text).digest("hex"));
var hexDigest = crypto.createHash('SHA1').update(text).digest("hex");
var hexStr;
}
```

Kindly help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function generateHashCode(text)
{
    // assuming text is UTF-8 encoded

    var crypto = require('crypto');
    var hexDigest = crypto.createHash('SHA1').update(text).digest(); // this should be .digest() not .digest('hex')

    var hexStr = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < hexDigest.length; i++) {
        hexStr += (((hexDigest[i] - 0x100) & 0xff) + 0x100).toString(16).substr(1); // fixed some math issues here
    }

    var hashid = 0;
    var a = 'a'.charCodeAt(0); // or just var a = 97;
    for (var i = 0; i < hexStr.length; i++)
        hashid += Math.abs(Math.pow(27, 10 - i) * (a - (1 + hexStr.charCodeAt(i))));

    return hashid;
}

console.log(generateHashCode("batman"));
```

Comment: Thanks! the last iteration returns NaN

Comment: @user3671807 Where exactly? explain more!

Comment: hashid in the last for loop returns NaN, not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: @user3671807 I forgot to make thse strings into numbers. Check the new answer!

Comment: Just note that I actually didn't test the code, I just transformed that Java code into Javascript.

Comment: Thanks a lot.One last doubt,  I am comparing the output from java and javascript. Both are different not sure how to make it same.

Comment: @user3671807 I tried it on my computer and as you said it doesn't give the same result so I fixed it. Now it return pretty much the same result as the Java code you provided. (just keep in mind Javascript is not the best in math).

Comment: yes, it is pretty much the same. You have made my life easier!